# Java Proto generation cannot find sources

Tags: grpc, grpc-java, proto

I am trying out a sample GRPC project and am using Java 8 with gradle 7. I seem to have the right dependencies and configs for proto generation to generate Java sources. However, the task step for generateProto simply succeeeds and I see this:
`generateProto NO-SOURCE`

My project skeleton is here and pretty straightforward https://github.com/sellmart/cfs. Appreciate any input on why the sources aren't being generated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proto plugin did not find any proto source files.

Your proto is in the `src/proto` directory. The proto folder structure mirrors that of the java folder structure; you should use folders like `src/main/proto` and `src/test/proto`.

Comment: Thank you. Moving the proto folder under src/main/ worked.